# Is it possible to join one table which compares itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a task to compare (like Excel) content in 2 versions.

Content is defined as a set of columns (field_id), which can have 1 or more positions with values (string_value).

I am trying to join one table (SOURCE) with itself where can I compare value on positions for different versions.

SOURCE: document_positions

```
+-------------+------------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| document_id | document_version | field_id | position | string_value |
+-------------+------------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 471         | 1                |1         | 1        | 5            |
| 471         | 1                |1         | 2        | 3            |
| 471         | 1                |1         | 3        | 7            | <- no position in version 2
| 471         | 1                |2         | 3        | 4            | <- no position in version 2
| 471         | 2                |1         | 1        | 5            | <- same value on position in version 1
| 471         | 2                |1         | 2        | 1            | <- diff value on position in version 1
| 471         | 2                |1         | 4        | 8            | <- no position in version 1
```

RESULT:

```
+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| document_id | field_id | position | VERSION_A | VALUE_V1 | VERSION_B | VALUE_V2 |
+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 471         | 1        | 1        | 1         | 5        | 2         | 5        | <- same value on position in version 1
| 471         | 1        | 2        | 1         | 3        | 2         | 1        | <- diff value on position in version 1
| 471         | 1        | 3        | 1         | 7        | 2         | NULL     | <- no position in version 2
| 471         | 2        | 3        | 1         | 4        | 2         | NULL     | <- no position in version 2
| 471         | 1        | 1        | 4         | NULL     | 2         | 8        | <- no position in version 1
+-------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Due to requirement there are no NULL values in the tables, so if version does not have a value on position 5, there is no record for it like (position:5 value: NULL).

It's not a great example but I'm trying use following sql and recevied to much results without NULLs.

```
SELECT 
    A.document_id, A.field_id, A.position, 
    A.document_version AS VERSION_A, A.string_value AS VALUE_V1, 
    B.document_version AS VERSION_B, B.string_value AS VALUE_V2
FROM
    document_position A
FULL JOIN 
    document_position B ON A.document_id = B.document_id
FULL JOIN 
    template_fields F ON A.field_id = F.id
                      AND B.field_id = F.id
                      AND A.document_id = B.document_id 
                      AND a.field_id = b.field_id 
                      AND a.position = B.position
                      AND a.document_version = 1 and b.document_version = 2
WHERE
    A.document_id = 471 ;
```

Is it possible to do with 1 sql statement?

Comment: Your `FULL JOIN`s don't make sense with your `WHERE`. The `FULL (OUTER) JOIN`s mean you are stating, in the `JOIN`s, you want rows from the tables aliased as `A`, `B` and `F` regardless of if you find related rows in the other tables. Due to your `WHERE`, however, they are **not** `FULL JOIN`s, they are `LEFT JOIN`s; is that intentional? If it is, why are you using `FULL JOIN`s? If not, you need to use a derived table and move the `WHERE` to that.

Comment: Example of undesired behaviour/incorrect `JOIN` usage: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mO1BxCrZ)

Comment: Is the aim to compare only 2 versions at any one time with your query?

Comment: Yes, I am comparing only 2 versions.